# Find the sun of ${x\over(x+1)}+{x^2\over(x+1)(x^2+1)}+{x^4\over(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)}+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, geometric-progressions

> Find the sum of $$
> \frac{\text{x}}{\text{x}+1}+\frac{\text{x}^2}{\left( \text{x}+1 \right) \left( \text{x}^2+1 \right)}+\frac{\text{x}^4}{\left( \text{x}+1 \right) \left( \text{x}^2+1 \right) \left( \text{x}^4+1 \right)}+...
> $$
>   where $x>1$

This is a question from *The Art and Craft of Problem Solving*. I tried using partial fraction, but it did not seem plausible for me. Also, I can not spot how to use the condition x>1

Comment: ... found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Ctext%7Bx%7D%7D%7B%5Ctext%7Bx%7D%2B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Ctext%7Bx%7D%5E2%7D%7B%5Cleft(%20%5Ctext%7Bx%7D%2B1%20%5Cright)%20%5Cleft(%20%5Ctext%7Bx%7D%5E2%2B1%20%5Cright)%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Ctext%7Bx%7D%5E4%7D%7B%5Cleft(%20%5Ctext%7Bx%7D%2B1%20%5Cright)%20%5Cleft(%20%5Ctext%7Bx%7D%5E2%2B1%20%5Cright)%20%5Cleft(%20%5Ctext%7Bx%7D%5E4%2B1%20%5Cright)%7D%2B...%24&p=1)